# How to rename files in order

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I need to sort and rename files in a test directory such that based on the bolded number the file will be renamed 1-5 in groups of 5. I was able to sort them but now need to rename them 1,2,3,4, or 5. This is what I have so far:

```
 find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' | sort -nt_ -k2,2 -k7,7
./FoilHole_6862563_Data_6834945_6834947_20190608_255634_Image.txt
./FoilHole_6862563_Data_6834952_6834954_20190608_255710_Image.txt
./FoilHole_6862563_Data_6834959_6834961_20190608_255748_Image.txt
./FoilHole_6862563_Data_6834935_6834937_20190608_255827_Image.txt
./FoilHole_6862563_Data_6834967_6834969_20190608_255906_Image.txt
./FoilHole_6862568_Data_6834945_6834947_20190608_060123_Image.txt
./FoilHole_6862568_Data_6834952_6834954_20190608_060159_Image.txt
./FoilHole_6862568_Data_6834959_6834961_20190608_360237_Image.txt
./FoilHole_6862568_Data_6834935_6834937_20190608_460316_Image.txt
./FoilHole_6862568_Data_6834967_6834969_20190608_560354_Image.txt
```

What I now need to do is rename them as:

```
./FoilHole_6862563_Data_6834945_6834947_20190608_1_Image.txt
./FoilHole_6862563_Data_6834952_6834954_20190608_2_Image.txt
./FoilHole_6862563_Data_6834959_6834961_20190608_3_Image.txt
./FoilHole_6862563_Data_6834935_6834937_20190608_4_Image.txt
./FoilHole_6862563_Data_6834967_6834969_20190608_5_Image.txt
./FoilHole_6862568_Data_6834945_6834947_20190608_1_Image.txt
./FoilHole_6862568_Data_6834952_6834954_20190608_2_Image.txt
./FoilHole_6862568_Data_6834959_6834961_20190608_3_Image.txt
./FoilHole_6862568_Data_6834935_6834937_20190608_4_Image.txt
./FoilHole_6862568_Data_6834967_6834969_20190608_5_Image.txt
```

Comment: try `man rename`

Answer (score 0):

As hacky `bash` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r file; do
  newprefix=${file%%_Data*}
  if [ "$prefix" != "$newprefix" ]; then
    cnt=1
    prefix=$newprefix
  fi
  newfile=$(echo "$file" | sed "s/[0-9]*\(_Image.txt\)/$cnt\1/")
  echo mv "$file" "$newfile"
  ((cnt++))
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' | sort -nt_ -k2,2 -k7,7)
```

Output:

```
$ ./script.sh
mv ./FoilHole_6862563_Data_6834945_6834947_20190608_255634_Image.txt ./FoilHole_6862563_Data_6834945_6834947_20190608_1_Image.txt
mv ./FoilHole_6862563_Data_6834952_6834954_20190608_255710_Image.txt ./FoilHole_6862563_Data_6834952_6834954_20190608_2_Image.txt
mv ./FoilHole_6862563_Data_6834959_6834961_20190608_255748_Image.txt ./FoilHole_6862563_Data_6834959_6834961_20190608_3_Image.txt
mv ./FoilHole_6862563_Data_6834935_6834937_20190608_255827_Image.txt ./FoilHole_6862563_Data_6834935_6834937_20190608_4_Image.txt
mv ./FoilHole_6862563_Data_6834967_6834969_20190608_255906_Image.txt ./FoilHole_6862563_Data_6834967_6834969_20190608_5_Image.txt
mv ./FoilHole_6862568_Data_6834945_6834947_20190608_060123_Image.txt ./FoilHole_6862568_Data_6834945_6834947_20190608_1_Image.txt
mv ./FoilHole_6862568_Data_6834952_6834954_20190608_060159_Image.txt ./FoilHole_6862568_Data_6834952_6834954_20190608_2_Image.txt
mv ./FoilHole_6862568_Data_6834959_6834961_20190608_360237_Image.txt ./FoilHole_6862568_Data_6834959_6834961_20190608_3_Image.txt
mv ./FoilHole_6862568_Data_6834935_6834937_20190608_460316_Image.txt ./FoilHole_6862568_Data_6834935_6834937_20190608_4_Image.txt
mv ./FoilHole_6862568_Data_6834967_6834969_20190608_560354_Image.txt ./FoilHole_6862568_Data_6834967_6834969_20190608_5_Image.txt
```

The counter variable `cnt` is reset to `1` whenever the filename prefix changes, e.g. when `./FoilHole_6862563` changes to `./FoilHole_6862568`.
To really rename the files you have to remove the `echo` in the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `bash` arithmetic with the `rename` command:

```
i=0
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' |
sort -nt_ -k2,2 -k7,7 |
while read filename ; do
    rename -v "s/[0-9]+_Image/$((i%5+1))_I/" ${filename}
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

Try it out with the `-n` option of the `rename` command, that just shows what is being done.

**WARNING**:

Filenames come from a piped input and the variable `filename` is set using the `read` builtin here. This *WILL* break if your filenames do not match the format you specified in your question, e.g. filenames with spaces, newlines, etc. So be aware that you would need to use a different approach then, e.g. `find`'s `-print0` option in combination with `xargs -0`.

In this case a helper file for the counter is used and `?` used as the variable replacement:

```
echo -1 > file_counter
find -name '*txt' -print0 |
sort -znt_ -k2,2 -k7,7 |
xargs -I ? -0 bash -c '
     i=$(($(cat file_counter)+1))
     rename -n -v "s/[0-9]+_Image/$(($i%5+1))/"  ?
     echo $i > file_counter
'
```